# How To awake app in background , if app is in doze mode or in deep sleep mode?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

To awake app in background , I have tried with high priority push , also with Alarm Manager or work Manager all things we have tried but nothing works for android 12 & 13 for some chinese phones , we are unable to awake.

Tried :- High Priority Push , Alarm Manager , Work Manager

Expecting :- what's the best practices for awake app in background that we can follow ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should be able to use `AlarmManager#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) to wake the device and deliver an Intent. But that depends on the OS - some versions (like MIUI) have aggressive power-saving behaviour by default, and you need to whitelist apps to make them responsive. That's why you have sites like https://dontkillmyapp.com so you can point users to a guide on how to make things work the way they should